# unset parent class styles with same name

Tags: css, sass, less

I have two class with same name one is injected on top, and other is injected on child of page-container.

I would like to unset all properties of top class. But only its properties. For example i wanna keep  `div` specific properties for this class. But `all:unset` removes all styles not only styles of `.page-header` example below:

```css
.page-header {
  padding: 10px; // unset this one
}

div {
  background-color: red; // i wanna keep this style
}

.my-page-container {
  .page-header {
    all: unset;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

I know that i can just override style on child class like `padding: unset`, but i am searching for approach that covers all styles of this class at once.

Comment: _“But all:unset removes all styles not only styles of .page-header”_ - of course it does, because this works on the propery level, not a rule level. I don’t think what you want, is actually possible in any way other than that you would specifically list each propety you want to unset individually. The alternative would be to change what classes you apply to where to begin with.

Comment: Thank you, i guess i will just change my child class name.